# Webpack file-loader custom path

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm having multiple entries like this:

```
entry:{
    'dist/folder1/video.mp4': 'src/folder1/video.mp4',
    'dist/folder2/otherfolder/video2.mp4': 'src/folder2/otherfolder/video2.mp4'
}
```

I'm using file-loader for handling the .mp4 files and i want to keep all the relative folders a part from 'src' in the dist output folder.

It seems that this way of setting up entries works for webpack but not for file-loader since it's removing all the paths but the filename.

Using the useRelativePath parameter only makes the entries keep their original part including src folder.
Also using outputPath parameter allows you to use only one single output folder for all the files.

Is there a way to achieve this?